# SQl results duplication

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE [Distributors]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)

INSERT INTO [Distributors]([Name]) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO [Distributors]([Name]) VALUES ('B')

CREATE TABLE [Points]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Distributor_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Point_Count] [int] NULL,
    [Point_Type] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Point_Level] [int] NULL,
    [From_Distributor] [int] NULL,
    [Is_Calculated] [bit] NULL,
    [Point_Date] [datetime]
)

INSERT INTO [Points] ([Distributor_ID], [Point_Count], [Point_Type],[Point_Level], [From_Distributor], [Is_Calculated], [Point_Date])     
VALUES(1, 1, 'AN', '', 2, 'True', '2015-02-16')
INSERT INTO [Points] ([Distributor_ID], [Point_Count], [Point_Type],[Point_Level], [From_Distributor], [Is_Calculated], [Point_Date])     
VALUES(1, 1, 'Offer', '', 2, 'True', '2015-02-16')`

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Profit]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Distributor_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Profit] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Percentage] [int] NULL,
    [Profit_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [From_Distributor_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Is_Paid] [bit] NULL,
    [Paid_By] [int] NULL
)

INSERT INTO [Profit]([Distributor_ID], [Profit], [Percentage],[Profit_Date], [From_Distributor_ID], [Is_Paid], [Paid_By]) 
VALUES (1, '80', 10, '2015-02-16', 2, 'False', 0)

INSERT INTO [Profit]([Distributor_ID], [Profit], [Percentage],[Profit_Date], [From_Distributor_ID], [Is_Paid], [Paid_By]) 
VALUES (1, '40', 5, '2015-02-16', 2, 'False', 0)
```

When I do the select query with join statement I face a duplication

```
SELECT distinct Points.[ID]
  ,Points.[Distributor_ID]
  ,[Point_Count]
  ,[Point_Type]
  ,[Point_Level]
  ,[From_Distributor]
  ,[Is_Calculated]
  ,[Point_Date]
  --,Profit.Profit
FROM 
   [Points]
INNER JOIN 
   Profit ON Points.From_Distributor = Profit.From_Distributor_ID 
          AND Points.Distributor_ID = Profit.Distributor_ID
WHERE 
    (Points.[Distributor_ID] = 1) 
    AND ([Point_Date] >= '2/16/2015') 
    AND ([Point_Date] <= '2/28/2015')
```

results  are tow rows

when using " Profit.Profit " in the select statement it got 4 rows
i think problem in join statement
please i need your advice

Comment: I get nothing with your query...

Comment: No, there is **no duplication** (if I remove all the `WHERE` conditions) - all the four rows returned as **different** from one another! What is your *desired* output then??

Comment: no row of the sample data you provide meets the `WHERE`-criteria in your sample `SELECT`

Comment: i have to use the where condition and the results must be two rows only

Comment: What two rows? It seems you did not include the rows you expect to find in your result set into your sample data.

Comment: please check again i have edited the question text

Comment: Can you post your results from the following q's please? select * from points. select * from profit. and your select.. join query. :)

Comment: ID Distributor_ID Point_Count Point_Type Point_Level From_Distributor Is_Calculated Point_Date
1 1 1 AN 0 2 1 2/16/2015
2 1 1 Offer 0 2 1 2/16/2015

and after using Profit.Profit in select query


ID Distributor_ID Point_Count Point_Type Point_Level From_Distributor Is_Calculated Point_Date Profit
1 1 1 AN 0 2 1 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000 40.00
1 1 1 AN 0 2 1 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000 80.00
2 1 1 Offer 0 2 1 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000 40.00
2 1 1 Offer 0 2 1 2015-02-16 00:00:00.000 80.00
@Rainhider

Comment: the first thing I see is that the point_date is different in both, but it's hard to tell because it is not a screenshot

Comment: I really need screenshots so I can see what values match up with what columns.

Comment: how to upload an image here?